# Unitary method - Elementary school math

Tags: education, fractions, percentages, ratio

Girls are 60% of the total students and are 18 in number.
The unitary method goes like this:-

100/60*18=30

My question- Don't fractions work the other way around?(i.e.,part/whole)?what just happened here? Please explain in simple terms. Thank you.

Comment: You have the unknown quantity $T$ representing the total number of students and you know that $18=\frac{60}{100}\times T$. Therefore $T=18\div\left(\frac{60}{100}\right)=18\times\frac{100}{60}$.

Comment: This is more of an algebra problem and helps if you take a variable but unitary method can be used too. If $60$ out of $100$ are girls. So if there are $\frac{100}{60}$ students then $1$ out of them would be a girl. Hence if there are $\frac{100}{60}\cdot 18$ students then $18$ of them would be girls .

Comment: You see, this is where I get confused. If 60 out of 100 are girls wouldn't you write it as 60/100 instead of 100/60(here it is,whole/part instead of part/whole) or am I misunderstanding sth please help